# How to create a new partition on FileVault disk on MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, partition, filevault, guid

I have a 500GB disk on MacOS encrypted with FileVault 2.

I have successfully resized the disk to 250GB.

Now I want to create another partition to install another MacOS on the 250GB free-space of the disk.

But DiskUtility failed on me, it just can't create the new partition I wanted and showed me no error at all.

How could I safely create the new partition I need?

This the result printed out from the command `$ sudo gpt -r show disk0`

```
          start       size  index  contents
              0          1         PMBR
              1          1         Pri GPT header
              2         32         Pri GPT table
             34          6         
             40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
         409640  488940896      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
      489350536    1269760      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
      490620296  486484731         
      977105027         32         Sec GPT table
      977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 500 GB disk has about 250 GB of unallocated disk space (starting at block 490620296 and ending at block 977105026).

To create a new partition in the unallocated disk space you have to boot to another boot disk.

**Preparation:**

- Attach a backup drive and backup your drive.
- Detach the backup drive
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan). If you boot to a full system and login as admin you have to prepend `sudo` to execute some commands like `gpt ...` or `newfs_hfs ...`!

**Modify the GUID partition table and add a new partition**

- Enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/diskX` (with diskX: the disk identifier of your internal disk (probably disk0)) to get an overview. In the commands below I assume the disk identifier is disk0.
- Now add a new partition with:

  ```
  gpt add -b StartBlock -i IndexNumber -s size -t type disk #size has to be dividable through 8!
  ```

  In your case:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2 #unmount the FileVault2 volume if unlocked
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 490620296 -i 4 -s 486484728 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Get the disk identifier of the new partition

  ```
  diskutil list #probably disk0s4
  ```
- Format the new partition:

  ```
  newfs_hfs -v "Volume Name" -J /dev/disk0s4
  ```
- To quit Terminal enter:

  ```
  exit
  ```

  and quit Terminal
- Open Disk Utility to verify the new volume
- Reboot

**In case you want to move the recovery partition to the end of the disk first**

This is not recommended if your first main volume is encrypted with FileVault2. The first Recovery HD contains some encryption keys to unlock the FileVault2 volume. Moving/changing the Recovery HD may render your FileVault2 volume unaccessible and useless.

- Create a new recovery partition and clone the old one:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2 #unmount the FileVault2 volume if unlocked
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 975835264 -i 4 -s 1269760 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  dd if=/dev/disk0s3 of=/dev/disk0s4
  ```
- remove the old recovery partition and add a new normal partition

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 489350536 -i 3 -s 486484728 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Get the disk identifier of the new partition

  ```
  diskutil list #probably disk0s3
  ```
- Format the new partition:

  ```
  newfs_hfs -v "Volume Name" -J /dev/disk0s3
  ```
- To quit Terminal enter:

  ```
  exit
  ```
- Open Disk Utility to verify the new volume
- Reboot